# Can the Grave Domain cleric's Spare the Dying cantrip still be cast as a regular action?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, actions, cantrips

The [Grave Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#GraveDomain) (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 19-20) gets the Circle of Mortality feature at 1st level, part of which states:

> In addition, you learn the [*spare the dying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spare-the-dying) cantrip, which doesn’t count against the number of cleric cantrips you know. For you, it has a range of 30 feet, and you can cast it as a bonus action.

This wording seems to imply the option, rather than necessity, to cast it as a bonus action. Am I correct in assuming this? Can I still cast it as an action and have my bonus action available?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The text says "you can cast it as a bonus action." Can cast, as opposed to must cast, denotes an option, not a requirement. This has no effect on the default option to cast this spell as an action.

Comment: The PHB in 5e always uses the phrase "You can do y as x type action" or "you can use your x to do y". eg. "**Breath Weapon.** You can use your action to exhale destructive energy. " This seems to avoid anyone misreading that you MUST use your breath weapon as your action. Or you MUST cast it as a bonus action. This doesn't mean you can use another action type.